intervlan routing on cisco L3 stacked switches
I am new to this and I am having a bit of a issue trying to successfully perform intervlan routing on a stacked L3 switche(s).
I essentially have three SVIs with their corresponding VLANS ( i think)
The issue I am facing is that i cannot ping any endpoint to another in a different VLAN.
I feel like I might be missing something stupid simple?
Below is the switch config along with excerpts of the interfaces.
!
!
!
no aaa new-model
switch 1 provision c9200l-48p-4x
switch 2 provision c9200l-48p-4x
switch 3 provision c9200l-48p-4x
switch 4 provision c9200l-48p-4x
switch 5 provision c9200l-48p-4x
!

ip routing
!
!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
!
!
!
ip igmp snooping querier
login on-success log
!
!
!
!
system mtu 9198
license boot level network-advantage addon dna-advantage
!
!
diagnostic bootup level minimal
!
spanning-tree mode rapid-pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
memory free low-watermark processor 10626
!
!

!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 vrf forwarding Mgmt-vrf
 ip address 192.168.10.69 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/4
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/5
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/6
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/7
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/8
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/9
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/10
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/40
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/41
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/42
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/43
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/44
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/45
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/46
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/47
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/48
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast

interface GigabitEthernet2/0/1
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/2
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/3
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/4
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/5
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/6
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/7
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/8
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/9
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/10
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast

!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/40
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/41
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/42
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/43
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/44
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/45
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/46
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/47
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/48
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast

interface GigabitEthernet3/0/1
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/2
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/3
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/4
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/5
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/6
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/7
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/8
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/9
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!

interface GigabitEthernet4/0/1
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet4/0/2
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet4/0/3
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet4/0/4
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet4/0/5
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet4/0/6
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet4/0/7
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet4/0/8
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet4/0/9
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!

interface GigabitEthernet4/0/40
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet4/0/41
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet4/0/42
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet4/0/43
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet4/0/44
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet4/0/45
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet4/0/46
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet4/0/47
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet4/0/48
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast

interface GigabitEthernet5/0/1
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/0/2
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/0/3
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/0/4
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/0/5
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/0/6
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/0/7
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/0/8
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/0/9
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!

interface GigabitEthernet5/0/40
 switchport access vlan 20
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/0/41
 switchport access vlan 20
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/0/42
 switchport access vlan 20
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/0/43
 switchport access vlan 20
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/0/44
 switchport access vlan 20
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/0/45
 switchport access vlan 20
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/0/46
 switchport access vlan 20
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/0/47
 switchport access vlan 20
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/0/48
 switchport access vlan 20
 switchport mode access
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 spanning-tree portfast

!
interface Vlan1
 ip address 192.168.10.10 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan10
 ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
 ip mtu 1500
!
interface Vlan20
 ip address 10.10.1.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan30
 ip address 10.20.1.1 255.255.255.0
!
!
!
end

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Did you create the vlans?  do show spanning-tree vlan 10 for example

I did. it output this, as an example
sho spanning-tree vlan 10
VLAN0010
Spanning tree enabled protocol rstp
Root ID    Priority    32778
Address     6c29.d25a.9b00
This bridge is the root
Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
Bridge ID  Priority    32778  (priority 32768 sys-id-ext 10)
Address     6c29.d25a.9b00
Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
Aging Time  300 sec
Along with the interfaces.

Did you configure the correct default gateway on your endpoints?  Can you ping them?  If the answer is yes, the next thing to check is that routing is enabled.  show ip route  You should see all your vlan interfaces listed.

Not sure about that specific model (might be IOS-XE?) but you might have to do a 'no shutdown' under each layer 3 SVI.
Basically test as you would from bottom to top. Have a device ping its gateway, if you get a timeout, check for the MAC address showing up in the VLAN MAC table, check the ARP table on the switch, etc. Check the routing table as mentioned.

performing show ip route gives me this:
C        10.1.1.0/24 is directly connected, Vlan10
L        10.1.1.1/32 is directly connected, Vlan10
C        10.10.1.0/24 is directly connected, Vlan20
L        10.10.1.1/32 is directly connected, Vlan20
C        10.20.1.0/24 is directly connected, Vlan30
L        10.20.1.1/32 is directly connected, Vlan30```

I do get a timeout if i try to ping a device in, say, vlan 20, from a device in vlan 10... Nothing is appearing, from what i can in the arp table. I did verify that i performed no shutdown for each SVI

Just to clarify, If I need a device to communicate to vlan20, I need to configure it (device) with the default gateway I set for vlan20 correct? In this case, 10.20.1.1.

Yes any device must have its default gateway in the same network as its IP address. So a device connected to a port with 'switchport access vlan 20' must have an IP address in the appropriate network and with the appropriate gateway (ex. 10.10.1.10 and gateway 10.10.1.1 in this case).
Is there a reason you didn't do the obvious and have your networks align with the VLAN number? 10.10.0.0/24 is VLAN10, 10.20.0.0/24 is VLAN20, 10.30.0.0/24 is VLAN30, etc.?
Did you ping from a device to its own gateway? You need to do that first, like ping from 10.10.1.10 to 10.10.1.1 and see if it works.

haha...I actually am taking over this site from other people so..needless to say, the whole thing is a mess so i cant really tell you why they didnt segment these properly and neatly, and it's too late to change them because that would require changing IPs for all the endpoints. Essentially, i have been thrown to the sharks.
And I was able to ping from a device to it's appropriate gateway and got a response.

I also cannot ping gateway 10.20.1.1/24 on VLAN30 (gosh, that is confusing) from my PC that is on 10.1.1.248/24 (vlan10).  I really do feel that something stupid simple is being missed here...

Now try to ping from the switch command line terminal to the IP addresses of the SVIs and then to some devices on each network. Note that if you only have Windows computers on the network they might block ping (ICMP) by default so everything will seem to timeout. Disable the Windows firewall for a few moments for testing if you can before trying to ping to the computer from the switch. Then check the ARP table and MAC table on the switch to see what is there. ( 'show ip arp' and 'show mac address-table')

So i am able to ping the networks and devices in them and get a response. When i do show arp i do see the entries for the ones i pinged. I pinged the gateways as well.

That suggests everything is working fine. Your ability to move traffic between the networks might simply be firewall configuration on the end user devices or misconfiguration of the end user devices (bad gateway for example). If the switch has routing enabled, has route table entries that are correct, has MAC and ARP table entries and can ping the end user devices and they can ping their gateway addresses, then everything is basically working.

It does seem that way. Although, for example I'm on Vlan10 and try to ping a device in vlan 20, it times out. I am really thinking of just redoing the SVIs but looking at thw running config, nothing seems out of the ordinary?

The only thing I see that is potentially wrong is that you have manually configured the speed on many of the ports. Gigabit should never require manual speed and duple configuration unless you are trying to configure a 10 gigabit SFP+ port for 1 gigabit link speed or something similar. For the huge majority of devices you should not manually configure the speed and duplex.
What does the output of 'show mac address-table' and 'show ip arp' look like? What about 'show spanning-tree summary'?

Apologies for delay. I performed 'show ip arp' and it outputs a table with entries that look like this.
Internet  10.1.1.1                -   6c29.d25a.9b46  ARPA   Vlan10


'sho spanning tree summary' gives me this:
Root bridge for: VLAN0001, VLAN0010, VLAN0020, VLAN0030
EtherChannel misconfig guard     is enabled
Extended system ID                      is enabled
Portfast Default        is disabled
PortFast BPDU Guard Default            is disabled
Portfast BPDU Filter Default           is disabled
Loopguard Default                   is disabled
UplinkFast                      is disabled
BackboneFast      is disabled
Configured Pathcost method used is long

---------------------- -------- --------- -------- ---------- ----------
VLAN0001                     0         0        0          2          2
VLAN0010                     0         0        0        128        128
VLAN0020                     0         0        0          2          2
VLAN0030                   0         0        0         20         20
---------------------- -------- --------- -------- ---------- ----------
4 vlans                      0         0        0        152        152```

I also put all the interfaces speed and duplex back to auto and auto negotiate.

The fact that you have no ARP entries for VLAN interfaces other than VLAN 10 might indicate those VLAN interfaces (SVI) are down or there are no ports active in those VLANs so autostate has disabled the VLAN interfaces for the associated VLANs. You can do 'show interface vlan 10' and 'show interface vlan 20' and 'show interface vlan 30' etc. to see the state of the SVIs for each VLAN. IF they are not in Up/Up status, they will not work for forwarding traffic.

sho int vlan 10 shows:
Vlan10 is up, line protocol is up , Autostate Enabled
Hardware is Ethernet SVI, address is 6c29.d25a.9b46 (bia 6c29.d25a.9b46)
Description: Default Gateway for 10.1.1.0/24
Internet address is 10.1.1.1/24
MTU 9198 bytes, BW 1000000 Kbit/sec, DLY 10 usec,
reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
Keepalive not supported
ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00

sho int vlan 20 shows:
Vlan20 is up, line protocol is up , Autostate Enabled
Hardware is Ethernet SVI, address is 6c29.d25a.9b56 (bia 6c29.d25a.9b56)
Description: Default Gateway for 10.10.1.0/24
Internet address is 10.10.1.1/24
MTU 9198 bytes, BW 1000000 Kbit/sec, DLY 10 usec,
reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
Keepalive not supported
ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00

sho int vlan30 shows:
Vlan30 is up, line protocol is up , Autostate Enabled
Hardware is Ethernet SVI, address is 6c29.d25a.9b65 (bia 6c29.d25a.9b65)
Description: Default Gateway for 10.20.1.0/24
Internet address is 10.20.1.1/24
MTU 9198 bytes, BW 1000000 Kbit/sec, DLY 10 usec,
reliability 255/255, txload 19/255, rxload 1/255
Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set

Also, I appreciate you soo much for taking the time on this. It really has helped!!

Again, all of that seems exactly as it should be. IF you can ping those IP addresses (the gateway addresses) from the command line on the switch, then they should be working. Your route table seems fine, everything seems fine. You could check if the switch has any ACLs applied. 'show access-lists'
Other than that, I can only think there is a problem with the devices on the networks. Either wrong gateway or IP address or subnet mask configuration, or firewalls on the devices.

Understood! Thank you for all the guidance. :)
